Passing data sequentially to a Linear Regression model
I have a Pandas DataFrame having data of a certain product with three columns.

invoice_date - containing the invoice_date when an order for the product was placed. It is sorted as well as in datetime format.
prod_quantity - This contains the product quantity ordered for the respective invoice_date.
lag - contains the lag between two consecutive invoice_dates.

I am training a linear regression model on this data. the prod_quantity column is to be passed as an independent variable to predict the lag values.
The doubt I have is , how to pass the prod_quantity data sequentially?
For example- I want the first 200 prod_quantity values to be passed sequentially to predict the next lag values. How do I do it?
The model just takes random prod_quantity values in the training dataset.

Linear regression is not a time-series model so you will see examples of randomly selecting the training data because in theory the order shouldn't make any difference.
However given that you believe the order of the data matters and that time may be a critical element, there are some things you can do.

Build more features based on date, such as month, year, quarter, etc. so that the model may learn that during certain periods, certain things happen differently
Add a 'trend' column that starts at 1 and increases by 1 for each time period (ex. if you have 52 weeks of weekly data, this column would be 1-52, or essentially a row number).  Make sure your data is sorted in ascending order by date before assigning this
Look up out of time validation.  This is a cross validation method that forces the training/test data splits into windows that start at the beginning of your training data and expand across to force the model to evaluate accuracy following the temporal order of your data
Evaluate some tree based models as well, such as XGBoost in addition to OLS to see if the additional variables are helping

